# Google Maps Dead Zones and InfoWIndow Close Button Not Working

Tags: xml, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Interesting combination of problems with the Googles Maps API when parsing the markers with XML
I'm seeing deadzones, everything within is unclickable, including the map itself.
InfoWindows won't close clicking the close button (seem to be unclickable) or when clicking outside of the InfoWindows pane.

The Deadzone seems to disappear after the map is zoomed in, but the zoom distance isn't consistent per location.

Heres the code if anyone can make or heads or tales of it.
http://ymartino.userworld.com/prototype_maps/map_read_only2.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `position:relative` for the div map_canvas. That will fix the overlay div problem.

besides, it is not a zoomlevel problem. As you can see, your hand cursor disappears when you go over a part in the right hand side of the map.

EDIT: I tested your code myself, and the deadzone disappears once you set all position attributes to relative.

Comment: That doesn't seem to do it for me, I've still got the dead zone and unresponsive closing clicks.  Thanks though.

Comment: as for the event handler for the marker click, do not create a new infowindow on every click. Instead, create one infowindow outside the function.

Comment: Double check your results. are you being served a cached copy?

Comment: Actually I take all that back about the CSS, I don't know where my head is today, that worked. 

Now I just need to fix the function call.  Thanks.